# Excel typescript update chart data series

Tags: excel, typescript, charts, office-scripts

I have created an office script that does some operations on excel data and creates a table. The data of this table is the input for a chart. The chart is already existing in the Excel file.
Now I need to update the data range of the chart manually whenever new items are added to the table, but I want to do this automated ofcourse.
I was not able to find any documentation on this. In VBA I can update data ranges of a chart and I tried to port that to the office script, but with no luck.

in VBA it is like this:

```html
ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(1).XValues = "='summary and graph'!$A$2:$A$42"
ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(1).Values = "='summary and graph'!$B$2:$B$42"
ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(2).Values = "='summary and graph'!$C$2:$C$42"
```

What would be a way to do this in excel office script? What would the syntax be?

Thanks, Joris

Comment: Have you tried recording a script when you do it manually? You can do that via the Record Actions task pane.

Comment: Yes, I tried that, but somehow I cannot change the data series in Excel online, I can only change the layout of the chart, not the data series content. This, in combination with your remark would be the easiest solution. Thanks for commenting

Comment: Can you edit your original question and add the recorded code?

Comment: I cannot add the recorded code, since somehow I am not able to change the data in Excel online for this graph. When I create a graph in Excel Online myself, I can edit the data and record that, but I cannot edit the data of this graph in Excel online, the options are just grayed out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the code you get when you do the recording to create a chart for the table

```
function main(workbook: ExcelScript.Workbook) {
    let selectedSheet = workbook.getActiveWorksheet();
    let table1 = workbook.getTable("Table1");
    // Insert chart on sheet selectedSheet with source data from table1
    let chart_5 = selectedSheet.addChart(ExcelScript.ChartType.columnClustered, table1.getRange());
}
```

You can change the chart source data using the [setData](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/office-scripts/excelscript/excelscript.chart?view=office-scripts#setData_sourceData__seriesBy_) method.

You can also get the chart series collection using the [getSeries](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/office-scripts/excelscript/excelscript.chart?view=office-scripts#getSeries__) method, and set Values for each series using the [setValues](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/office-scripts/excelscript/excelscript.chartseries?view=office-scripts#setValues_sourceData_) method. Example code could be -

```
let seriesCollection = chart_5.getSeries();
let range = workbook.getWorksheet("summary and graph").getRange("B2:B42");
seriesCollection[0].setValues(range);
range = workbook.getWorksheet("summary and graph").getRange("C2:C42");
seriesCollection[1].setValues(range);
```

Comment: Thanks, this is working indeed. With your links I indeed found more information about this syntax.
Only thing that is not working is the changing of the X-axis values. But that might be because of the way the chart is created. I am still looking into that, but I need to find some time.